# Plotly.js default colors list

Tags: javascript, colors, plotly

How do I obtain the default colors list / palette for plots with multiple series? (e.g. bubble chart)

Comment: Got the function which generates the color, you have to pass an integer to the getColor function.
var getColor = Plotly.d3.scale.category20();

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Plotly uses the same [colors](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/v2.14.0/src/components/color/attributes.js#L5-L16) as in `d3`'s `scale.category10()` function. After 10 colors the whole color scheme starts again from 0.

The colors codes can be found in [KDD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44727682/2776376). The snippet below gives the d3 colors and takes the Plotly colors dynamically from a plot, i.e. even if the Plotly changes the color codes will be correct.

```js
var d3colors = Plotly.d3.scale.category10();
var color_div = document.getElementById('colors');
var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i += 1) {
  data.push({
    x: [i],
    y: [i + 1],
    name: i + ": Color: " + d3colors(i),
    type: 'bar'
  });
}
Plotly.plot('colors', data);

var node;
var textnode;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  var color = d3colors(i);
  node = document.createElement("div");
  node.style.color = color;
  var text = "D3: " + color;
  textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  node.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  var rgb = Plotly.d3.selectAll('.point').selectAll('path')[i][0].style.fill;
  color = Plotly.d3.rgb(rgb).toString()
  var text = "Plotly: " + color + " ; " + rgb;
  textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  color_div.appendChild(node); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="colors"></div>
```

Comment: Note: as of v2, `Plotly` no longer exposes `.d3` so you'll need to separately-load the `d3` library if you want to call methods on it.

Comment: ...and the incantation is: `d3.schemeCategory10[...]`. Also, a [link](https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js) to the minified version of `d3` (7.x).

Comment: You can find the gist of it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/ab784140d66b39508fea1244f1a317e9).

Answer (score 71):

For **Plotly.js**, the default color list is given in the [source code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/v2.14.0/src/components/color/attributes.js#L5-L16):

```
'#1f77b4',  // muted blue
'#ff7f0e',  // safety orange
'#2ca02c',  // cooked asparagus green
'#d62728',  // brick red
'#9467bd',  // muted purple
'#8c564b',  // chestnut brown
'#e377c2',  // raspberry yogurt pink
'#7f7f7f',  // middle gray
'#bcbd22',  // curry yellow-green
'#17becf'   // blue-teal
```

For **Plotly Python**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64602359/365102).

If a plot has more than 10 series, it will cycle back to the first color.

Comment: In Python, this list can be retrieved directly as `plotly.colors.DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS`

Comment: Other, comparable lists of pre-made colors can be retrieved from plotly.colors.qualitative

Comment: `Plotly.d3.scale.category10().range()`

Comment: But @sarah-messer these are not the default colors used :-(

Answer (score 12):

For **Plotly Python**, the default color palette can be determined via:

```py
>>> import plotly as px
>>> px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
[
    '#636EFA',
    '#EF553B',
    '#00CC96',
    '#AB63FA',
    '#FFA15A',
    '#19D3F3',
    '#FF6692',
    '#B6E880',
    '#FF97FF',
    '#FECB52',
]
```

...as described in the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express).

Comment: The default blue color is "#636EFA". Adding here so people don't have to try each color manually.

Answer (score 7):

While you're asking about bubble charts, I was asking the same question about Plotly.js pie charts. The search brought up your question for me.

Surprisingly it differs from how other charts work, so I'd like to post this information here, because I think it might be useful for someone who as myself is searching about how default colors work in pie charts. This question has "How to get Plotly.js default colors list?" as title and my answer is a special case for this question.

On August 3rd [there was a commit](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/commit/d50334e8a16b033f4613cc310a17559e03865afd) in Plotly.js which introduced extended colors for pie charts which adds 20 more colors to the base `category10` color scale.

There is now the `extendpiecolors` layout attribute for pie charts. Its description at [the source code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/41d870bca6049c7f7d102d5290e2425aa32fd8cf/src/traces/pie/layout_attributes.js#L32) says:

> If `true`, the pie slice colors (whether given by `piecolorway` or
>               inherited from `colorway`) will be extended to three times its
>               original length by first repeating every color 20% lighter then
>               each color 20% darker. This is intended to reduce the likelihood
>               of reusing the same color when you have many slices, but you can
>               set `false` to disable.
>               Colors provided in the trace, using `marker.colors`, are never extended.

I found no simple way of getting the actual color set out of Plotly.js data. However there is [the source code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/41d870bca6049c7f7d102d5290e2425aa32fd8cf/src/traces/pie/calc.js#L171-L188) of the function, which generates the extended colors and it is quite simple to copy it and use in your own source code to get the same color list as Plotly.js uses for pie charts by default. Plotly.js is MIT-licensed so it's allowed to use their code in your project.

I rewrote this function in the following way and now it simply generates the color range identical to what Plotly.js uses for piecharts by default. I used ES2015 notation. It also depends on `tinycolor` but this is a dependency of Plotly.js too so it shouldn't be a problem if you're already using Plotly.js

```
import Plotly from 'plotly.js/lib/core'
import tinycolor from 'tinycolor2'

function piechartExtendedColors() {
  var colorList = Plotly.d3.scale.category10().range();
  var pieColors = colorList.slice();

  colorList.forEach(color => {
      pieColors.push(tinycolor(color).lighten(20).toHexString());
  });

  colorList.forEach(color => {
      pieColors.push(tinycolor(color).darken(20).toHexString());
  });

  return pieColors;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: as of Plotly v2, this no longer works, because Plotly.d3 is no longer exposed, therefore Plotly.d3.scale.category10() does not work.
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/5400

There's probably a better way, but for simplicity, I'm just hard-coding:

```
const D3Colors = [
  '#1f77b4',
  '#ff7f0e',
  '#2ca02c',
  '#d62728',
  '#9467bd',
  '#8c564b',
  '#e377c2',
  '#7f7f7f',
  '#bcbd22',
  '#17becf'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this to retrieve the colours used in your plot:

```
return.plot_ly.ColorsUsed <- function( plotlyObject ) {

      explorePlot = plotly_json(plotlyObject)
      explorePlot = jsonlite::fromJSON(explorePlot$x$data)

      # Extract colors, names and fillcolors
      colors = explorePlot$data$marker$color
      names = explorePlot$data$name
      fillcolors = explorePlot$data$marker$fillcolor



      # Returns a list with the names, colors and fillcolors used in the plot
      toReturn = list( "names" = names,
                       "colors" = colors,
                       "fillcolors" = fillcolors )

      return(toReturn)


} # End FUnction return.plot_ly.ColorsUsed
```

Answer (score 0):

See also
https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic

E.g.:
https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic/blob/main/src/categorical/category10.js specifies the string `1f77b4ff7f0e2ca02cd627289467bd8c564be377c27f7f7fbcbd2217becf`. Splitting this string yields

[image]

```js
colors = "1f77b4ff7f0e2ca02cd627289467bd8c564be377c27f7f7fbcbd2217becf".match(/.{1,6}/g)

for (c of colors) {
    div = document.createElement('div')
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#" + c
    div.innerHTML = "#" + c
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].append(div)
}
```

Edit:
The `colors` array could previously be retrieved from `Plotly.d3.scale.category10().range()`, whereas now it seems to retrievable from
`Plotly.PlotSchema.get().layout.layoutAttributes.colorway.dflt`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute `colorway`. But is it available only after creating a plot (`graph._fullLayout.colorway`).

The colorway can be modified (https://plotly.com/javascript/colorway).